# append text when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I'm having an issue while trying to append text to a label when the checkbox is checked. When I submit the form the text is sent to an e-mailadress that is entered by the user with Mandrill.

The problem that I'm facing is that I always get the false value even if I have checked the checkbox. I have already looked at the "Check checkbox checked property" but none of the solutions work in my case. I have the following html & jQuery:

HTML:

```
<form id="vcardForm" method="post">
<input id="chkbox1" type="checkbox" />
<label id="lbl1"></label>
<input type="submit" id="submitbtn"/>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
if($('#chkbox1').is(':checked')) {
 $('#lbl1').append("\n Checked is true!");
}else {
  $('#lbl1').append("\n Checked is false!");
}

    </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to exclude the end form tag?

Comment: I seem to have forgotten to include it in my post, my bad. In my code it is included so that isn't the problem.

Comment: Its okay :) I do it all the time. I think you need an event to occur for this to work efficiently. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this? Where the event is on the checkbox?

**HTML**

```
<form id="vcardForm" method="post">
    <input id="chkbox1" type="checkbox" /> Check <br />
    <label id="lbl1"></label>
    <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" text="submit" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
$("#chkbox1").click( function()
{
    if($('#chkbox1').is(':checked')) 
    {
     $('#lbl1').text("Checked is true!");
    }
    else 
    {
      $('#lbl1').text("Checked is false!");
    }
});
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6txLq8uq/3/)

Comment: I've tried it and it works, thank you so much. I've been searching for hours for an answer

Comment: You are welcome. If I may, I would use classes to achieve this functionality in case you need to use it in more than one place. For example if you have more than one checkbox or if you use the functionality on other pages. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code inside ready handler, and you can use [html](http://api.jquery.com/html) to append text and line breaks:

```
$(function(){
if($('#chkbox1').is(':checked')) {
 $('#lbl1').html("<br />Checked is true!");//use <br /> instead of \n
}else {
  $('#lbl1').html("<br />Checked is false!");
}
});
```

If you want it when clicked then use the conditional code inside change event like below:

```
$(function(){
$('#chkbox1').on('change',function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#lbl1').html("<br />Checked is true!");//use <br /> instead of \n
  }else {
    $('#lbl1').html("<br />Checked is false!");
  }
});
});
```

Comment: `\n` is useless. It's just an escape

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#chkbox1').change(function(){
    if($('#chkbox1').is(':checked')) {
    $('#lbl1').append("\n Checked is true!");
  }else {
    $('#lbl1').append("\n Checked is false!");
  }
});
```

Try this and your problem is solved!

Comment: By doing this you are actually appending the text over and over again. Might want to clarify with the OP that this is what they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use on click of check box first and then check for is checked . Below is the code or u can refer [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AnkitaPalekar/wpn04kde/1/) js fiddle

```
$(document) .ready(function(){
$('#chkbox1').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
       {
          $('#lbl1').html('checked');
       }
       else
       {
          $('#lbl1').html('pls check ');
      }
})  });
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need: ***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/vopoto/1/edit?html,js,console,output)***

```
$("#chkbox1").change(function(){
  $('#lbl1').text("Checked is "+ this.checked +"!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var arr =[];
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
      arr.push($(this).parent('p').text()+'\n');
    });
    var array = arr.toString().split(',')
    $("#text").val(array.join(""));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Append text when checkbox is checked</p>
<textarea rows="4" id="text" style="width: 100%">
</textarea>


<div id="checkboxes">
  <p><input type="checkbox" ><span>&nbsp;&nbsp; Item 1</span></p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" ><span>&nbsp;&nbsp; Item 2</span></p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" ><span>&nbsp;&nbsp; Item 3</span></p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" ><span>&nbsp;&nbsp; Item 4</span></p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" ><span>&nbsp;&nbsp; Item 5</span></p>
</div>
```